Shopify Hydrogen - project no longer launches after updating to 2024.4
Since updating my Hydrogen project it now no longer launches when using the npm run dev command.

My project was working fine.
Decided to update package.json (and relevant files) to latest found in Templates > Skeleton.
Attempt to execute "npm run dev".
Failed to run / start local web server with absolutely no error.

See below for the command (and the lack of result)
PS C:\GitHub\XXXX\hydrogen\hydrogen> npm run dev

hydrogen@1.0.7 dev
shopify hydrogen dev --codegen

PS C:\GitHub\XXXX\hydrogen\hydrogen>

Package.json
{
  "name": "hydrogen",
  "private": true,
  "sideEffects": false,
  "version": "1.0.7",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "shopify hydrogen build --codegen",
    "dev": "shopify hydrogen dev --codegen",
    "preview": "npm run build && shopify hydrogen preview",
    "lint": "eslint --no-error-on-unmatched-pattern --ext .js,.ts,.jsx,.tsx .",
    "typecheck": "tsc --noEmit",
    "codegen": "shopify hydrogen codegen"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "defaults"
  ],
  "prettier": "@shopify/prettier-config",
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.2",
    "@headlessui/tailwindcss": "0.2.0",
    "@remix-run/react": "^2.8.0",
    "@remix-run/server-runtime": "^2.8.0",
    "@shopify/cli": "3.52.0",
    "@shopify/cli-hydrogen": "^8.0.0",
    "@shopify/hydrogen": "2024.4.0",
    "@shopify/remix-oxygen": "^2.0.4",
    "clsx": "^1.2.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "isbot": "^3.8.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-intersection-observer": "^9.4.1",
    "react-use": "^17.4.0",
    "schema-dts": "^1.1.0",
    "tiny-invariant": "^1.2.0",
    "typographic-base": "^1.0.4",
    "js-cookie": "3.0.5",
    "pdfmake": "0.2.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "5.0.2",
    "@playwright/test": "^1.40.1",
    "@remix-run/dev": "^2.8.0",
    "@remix-run/eslint-config": "^2.8.0",
    "@shopify/hydrogen-codegen": "^0.3.0",
    "@shopify/mini-oxygen": "^3.0.0",
    "@shopify/eslint-plugin": "^44.0.0",
    "@shopify/oxygen-workers-types": "^4.0.0",
    "@shopify/prettier-config": "^1.1.2",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.9",
    "@total-typescript/ts-reset": "^0.4.2",
    "@types/eslint": "^8.4.10",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.22",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.20.0",
    "eslint-plugin-hydrogen": "0.12.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "postcss-import": "^15.1.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^8.2.0",
    "prettier": "3.2.4",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "postcss-nesting": "11.2.2",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "0.5.11",
    "react-icons": "5.0.1",
    "@types/pdfmake": "0.2.9",
    "vite": "^5.1.0",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.0.0"
  }
}

Any ideas most appreciated - even if how to find out more diagnostic information.  Thanks.
Update #1
Good feedback on the below issue page
https://github.com/Shopify/hydrogen/issues/2000
I'm upgrading manually because I'm half way through changes on my main branch - you can use the upgrade command apparently but you need to do this before you make changes and only if your project is fully checked in.
But for some reason I am receiving the below error messages...
Warning: Could not find ts-node at 
 »   C:\GitHub\XXXX\hydrogen\hydrogen\node_modules\@shopify\cli\dist\index-e6f8190d.js. Please ensure that ts-node   
 »   is a devDependency. Falling back to compiled source.


Unhandled Rejection:  OTLPExporterError: Request Timeout
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (file:///C:/GitHub/XXXX/hydrogen/hydrogen/node_modules/@shopify/cli/dist/chunk-LKVSWZE2.js:46699:25)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at TLSSocket.socketCloseListener (node:_http_client:474:11)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:529:35)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at node:net:350:12
    at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:657:7) {
  data: undefined,
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
}
[Error: internal error]


try to remove package-lock.json and node_modules and clear the cache:
npm cache clean --force

then download the packages again
npm i

You can also try to check if the local node version fits with the package.json version:
"engines": {
   "node": ">=18.0.0"
}

without any error message is kinda hard to help you :) maybe it will help a little

Hi @Mike - tried your suggestion and no luck.  Node version and NPM both compatible.  Added specific error message to original question.

Hi @DanAbdn, in the error message I can see the ts-node error.
I myself use ts-node in the remix application, so it could work.
try to download it:
npm i ts-node

Sorry @Mike, no cigar, tried to install globally, dep / dev dep, removed node_modules, re-installed all, cleared npm cache then clean install of node_modules again.  You know that firewall popup from npm?  Do you know how to get this back? I think I dismissed it because I wasn't sure which app was requesting a firewall to be opened but realised it could have been node/npm.
